# How to apply a particular format of date of birth in a SQL query?

Tags: sql

Suppose I want a particular format of date of birth, like (mm-dd-yyyy).

How can I do that in SQL?

Comment: Which RDBMS? Date formatting functions are typically platform-specific

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CONVERT function if it is SQL SERVER

Select CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),Birthdate,110) from YourTable

Answer (score 3):

Although some people have listed the proper syntax for this in multiple RDBMSs (you really need to indicate which one you're using), I'd like to point out that formatting your data is typically something that should be done by the front end of your application. That's not to say that there's never a reason to do formatting in SQL, but usually it's best to just pass it as a date/time to the front end and let the front end handle how it will represent it to the user. Hopefully, you understand the difference between a date/time and a string.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your RDBMS is SQL Server, you can do the following:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), [DateOfBirth], 110)
```

There's more information about date formatting [here](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server

```
SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 110)

SELECT convert(varchar, DateOfBirth, 110) FROM YourTable
```

[How to format datetime & date in Sql Server 2005](http://anubhavg.wordpress.com/2009/06/11/how-to-format-datetime-date-in-sql-server-2005/)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Oracle:

```
select to_char(your_date_column,'MM-DD-YYYY') from your_date_table;
```